# Why Unauthorized Endpoint error coming even after adding Remote Endpoints?

Tags: apex, callout, tooling-api, queueable-interface, unauthorized-endpoint

Here is the error I'm getting when I try to call a Tooling API Rest Api:

```
00:53:19.0 (7411847)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|[28]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://vcorg-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/tooling/executeAnonymous/?anonymousBody=util.sendEmail%28%27%7B+recordId%3A+%221234TEST1234%22%2C+success%3A+%22TRUE%22%2C+result%3A+%22Executed+callback%22+%7D%27%29%3B, Method=GET]
00:53:19.0 (139800574)|CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[28]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]
```

I'm trying to call `Tooling API` to `executeanonymous` from within `APEX`. I've already added the Endpoint and even added other combination of endpoints such as without My Domain and `Visualforce` version of URL but the Error do not go away:

My End Points setup in Remote Setup are:

```
https://ap1.salesforce.com
https://vcorg-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
https://vcorg-dev-ed--pknmsp.ap1.visual.force.com
```

My Rest API code is being called in Queueable interface and my code is:

```
public with sharing class ApexServiceAsync implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    string functionCall    = 'util.sendEmail(\'test subject\');';

        HttpRequest req        = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        //string instance        = [select instanceName from Organization limit 1].instanceName.toLowerCase();
        //String baseUrl         = 'https://'+instance+'.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/tooling';
        String baseUrl         = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v36.0/tooling';
        String toolingendpoint = baseUrl + '/executeAnonymous/?anonymousBody='+encodingUtil.urlEncode(functionCall,'utf-8');
        req.setEndpoint(toolingendpoint);
        req.setMethod('GET');

        system.debug('@@ callbackFn [req]: '+req);

        Http h                 = new Http();
        h.send(req);
   }

}
```

and VF page button executes this function like this:

```
public void executeCB() {
        try {
         system.enqueueJob(new ApexServiceAsync());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            util.LogError(ex, true, true);
        }
    }
```

This is really frustrating, as I can execute the full HTTP Request code in Execute Anonymous window of Developer Console just fine and it works there, though it does not work when I call it from the page. What Unauthorized endpoint could there be in my case here?

Comment: Try to run the code with upgrading/downgrading version of your class.

Comment: I tried, that. I tried running it down from `30.0` to `37.0` and same error coming up.

Comment: i think when you run in class it takes some different URL. Check in debug

Comment: Your error message is not 'Unauthorized endpoint' but 'Unauthorized'. So the endpoint is probably fine, but the authentication is not.

Comment: That was it guys .. Thanks a bunch. Silliest mistake on my part, I mis-understood the Unauthorized error to be related to endpoint only. It was the session not getting passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unauthorized endpoint is returned from the API callout you are doing and not because of Remote site settings.

> For Apex code that is executed asynchronously, such as @future
>   methods, Batch Apex jobs, or scheduled Apex jobs, getSessionId returns
>   null.

Since you are calling using batch the session Id is null and hence its failing.

Comment: That is it. My mistake I wasn't looking into Session as my mind was fully into Endpoint security and just assumed it is coming from there. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Comment: note that as of winter 19, getSessionId() returns non-null in async contexts